# JavaFX using Platform.runLater and SwingUtilities.involkeLater

Tags: java

Would someone be able to give an example on using Platform.runLater and SwingUtilities.invokeLater with javaFX. I have attempted to use both and I am receiving the message :

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class Window$2 is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
    at javafx.application.Application.launch(Unknown Source)
    at Window$2.run(Window.java:50)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/389777815.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

The Class file is called Window and I not sure why it is saying Window$2, I would assume the $2 is some garbage from the memory printing out on the error. The code I am using is below. arguments is a static String[] since args is a not static. Also, when I use launch(Window.class, arguments); it throws the error then disappears quick but when I don't include Window.class it does not work at all. Shouldn't it assume it is calling the launch method from the same class? Also, launch(args) works fine outside the methods.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    arguments = new String[args.length];
    System.arraycopy(args, 0, arguments, 0, args.length);

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            launch(arguments);
        }
    }); 

    /*
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            launch(Window.class, arguments);
        }
    }); */
    //launch(args);
}
```

Comment: About class `Window$2`: `new Runnable()` creates an anonymous inner class of Window, which the compiler names `Windows$2`, the dollar being a valid identifier char.

Comment: Ok, so when I use launch(arguments) it assumes the class is Windows$2? Which is why SwingUtilities only worked with  launch(Window.class, arguments);?

Comment: The inner class (Window$2) has a `Window.this`, to access `arguments` and call `launch`. AFAIK main no longer is needed for JavaFX. You can simply use [getParameters()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters()). In an overriden init or start. _And the question gets irrelevant._

Comment: Thanks so much. It does make sense but would you be able to provide me with an example of using getParameters() instead of the main?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwingUtilities.involkeLater is normally obsolete, as JavaFX intends to replace Swing.
Platform.runLater unneeded, as launch may be called automagically.

Parameters can be fetched as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void init() {
        Parameters params = getParameters();
        Map<String, String> named = params.getNamed();
        System.out.println(named);
    }
```

If you have other than key=value parameters, check hte alternatives from [Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html).

Comment: This helps so thanks. Do you know if Platform.runLater is defiantly called? I ran into an issue with swing where my gui would appear before my calculations were done and this would avoid bugs later on. Why is this allowed without a main method? Is it because javafx runs on a separate thread then the other code? Am I able to have this and a main method? If so, which one is ran first?

Comment: @Ericode I think all of your questions are answered in the [JavaFX Application javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html).

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea. As for a swing resp. JavaFX on swing app: `setVisible(true);` is something to be called in `main` in the `invokeLater run`. My custom is to call `setVisible` explicitly on the frame object.